# How to turn off the scan for the war files in Jetty10

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-10

I am working with Jetty10 and by defalut, war scan is enabled and the scan interval is set to 1 second. It means Jetty scans the complete web apps directory every 1 sec. Please correct me if I am wrong.
the below code is in the jetty\etc\jetty-deploy.XML

```
 <Set name="scanInterval"><Property name="jetty.deploy.scanInterval" default="1"/></Set>
```

I don't want that burden to my application and turning this scan off will reduce the overhead of jetty scanning complete web apps every 1 sec.

So, my question is how can we turn off this scan? do we need to set it to -1 or is there any approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebAppProvider` uses a `org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner`, and the javadoc for `Scanner.setScanInterval(int)` says:

> @param scanInterval pause between scans in seconds, or 0 for no scan after the initial scan.

So if don't want regular scans after the initial scan you can set the scanInterval to 0 by setting the Jetty property `jetty.deploy.scanInterval=0` in your deploy.ini file.